# testing Touchscreen driver

Tags: automated-testing, embedded

I am testing a touch screen driver for an embedded device. Unfortunately it is tightly coupled to the hardware so simulated data can't be pushed in real time in order to simulate real usage.
Basic functional, manual, testing is easy but automation is not straight forward.

Anyone has experience with such an arrangement or can assist with ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There are somethings that are simply better tested manually, and I think that testing a touch screen is one of them.

Comment: Sorry, but not on this case... You can't really do a few hours stability test manually. Putting costs aside the straight forward solution is using a "robot" similar to an old pen plotter, but this is expensive and requires someone to program it.

Comment: @rsf you can't just put costs aside. This is something that you would either have very specalist hardware for or do it manually.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I am asking

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something years ago to test a graphics library that worked with a touch screen.  I never achieved an "unattended" automatic test.  My tests required human fingertips but instructed the tester on what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

This may be completely useless for your specific situation but I have used something similar to this for a past project that required me to do an automated reliability test.

http://hacknmod.com/hack/incredible-100-arduino-based-cnc-machine/

Replace the router with a stylus/finger analogue and code up your test patterns in Python.

---

There was something in the back of my mind that there was an easier way - Lego Mindstorms - Graphical programming interface and very flexible and may be within your budget.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced it's worth automating this kind of test, but if you want to try it you could use Lego Mindstorms to do it like [these guys](http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/02/lego-bot-built-to-test-knos-tablet-textbook-human-overlords-wa/) did.

Comment: That is cool :-) But the accuracy and reliability are probably not great.

Answer (score 0):

Which interface your touch screen is connected ?

Is it restive 4 wire or I2C ?

If it's I2C you can intercept and record I2C traffic and then automate.

If it's 4 wire analog, then things may get little bit harder.

For embedded C there are mocking libraries as well, but they are useful only when you do unit testing.

Comment: wow this is ancient history, but for the sake of others- the screen was SPI AFAIK, but you couldn't "cut the wire" to inject signals.